I cannot display a community toolkit maui popup in a view model
I want to have a message box popup show with a specific message. So I figure create a popup that can be displayed from a view model. So far I have created a popup called MsgBox and this is what I have:
XAML Code
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ctm:Popup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:ctm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
           xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:LockAndKeyMaui.ViewModels"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="LockAndKeyMaui.MsgBox"
           x:DataType="viewmodel:MsgViewModel"
           CanBeDismissedByTappingOutsideOfPopup="False">
    
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label
            Text="{Binding HdrTxt}"
            Margin="10,5,0,0"
            TextColor="White"
            FontSize="Medium"
            FontAttributes="Bold"/>
        <Label 
            Text="{Binding MsgTxt}"
            TextColor="Black" FontSize="Body"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ctm:Popup>

MsgBox code-behind
using CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views;
using LockAndKeyMaui.ViewModels;

namespace LockAndKeyMaui;

public partial class MsgBox : Popup
{
    public MsgBox(MsgViewModel msgVwMod)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = msgVwMod;
    }
}

MsgBox View Model
using CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace LockAndKeyMaui.ViewModels
{
    public class MsgViewModel : ObservableObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string msgtxt, hdrtxt;

        readonly IPopupService popupService;

        public MsgViewModel(IPopupService popupService)
        {
            this.popupService = popupService;
        }

        public string MsgTxt
        {
            get => msgtxt;
            set
            {
                this.msgtxt = value;
                OnPropChg(nameof(MsgTxt));
            }
        }

        public string HdrTxt
        {
            get => hdrtxt;
            set
            {
                hdrtxt = value;
                OnPropChg(nameof(HdrTxt));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropChg(string prName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prName));
        }
    }
}

And in a separate view model I'm trying to display it by setting up the view model like this:
namespace LockAndKeyMaui.ViewModels
{
    public partial class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public IPopupService popupService;

        public MainViewModel(IPopupService popServ)
        {
            Laks = new LakFuncs();
            popupService = popServ;
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        public static async Task CopyUsr(object sender)
        {
            var dataView = sender as SfDataGrid;

            PswdWthGrp row = (PswdWthGrp)dataView!.SelectedRow;

            if (row != null)
            {
                await Clipboard.SetTextAsync(row.UsrName);
                popupService.ShowPopupAsync<MsgViewModel>(onPresenting: vwMod => vwMod.PerformUpdts("User Name copied.", ""));
                await Task.Delay(1500);
                popupService.ClosePopup();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

But This is where I'm getting the problem. In the second view mode, when I try to display the MsgBox popup, popupService.ShowPopupAsync isn't even recognized. I even tried the command without the Async and it is still not recognized.
I would also like to be able to pass multiple variables to this popup.
So how can I get all of this to work?
